# ReferenceError: "e" is not defined | difficulties with multiple script running on just one sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For my work I made a spreadsheet which tracks the maintenance dates for all different tasks of †heir respective machine.

My scripts have been working just fine, but I noticed that it would run on all the pages I have in my Sheet.

So I have been searching for a solution, but I can't seem to make the different solutions I found work for me.

The script I have been using:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   if (e.range.getColumn() == 6) {
     e.range.offset(0, 3).setValue("")}
  };
  function onEdit2(e) {
   if ([10].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
     e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(newDate()).setNumberFormat("dd.MM.yyyy | HH:mm")};
}
```

With this I have been the closest to completing my quest (I think)

```
function Autoclear(e){

  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet(e);
  if(sheet.getName()=='Onderhoud'){
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
           if (e.range.getColumn() == 6) {
         e.range.offset(0, 3).setValue("")}
      }
  };

function Timestamp(e){

  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet(e);
  if(sheet.getName()=='Onderhoud'){
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
       
       if ([10].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
         e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd.MM.yyyy | HH:mm")};
}
}
```

This doesn't give me an error upon saving, but I do get the error message upon running.

> (ReferenceError: 'e' is not defined)

The main goal is to make the script work in 1 specific page: "Onderhoud"

How can I make this work? If there is something not correctly formatted or left information I will been more than happy the provide.

Comment: Get the name of the sheet tab that is active when the function was triggered, then if the name doesn't match Onderhoud, then quit.  `var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); if (sheet.getName() !== 'Onderhoud') {return;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script, instead of the ones you have

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var ind = [6, 10].indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
if (sheet.getName() == 'Onderhoud' && ind > -1) {
    if (ind === 0) {
        e.range.offset(0, 3).setValue(null)
    } else {
        e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd.MM.yyyy | HH:mm")
    };
};
}
```

As noted by Amit, edit the designated columns (instead of running the script from the script editor) to check if the script works.

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you very much for the quick response!

So if i read this correctly (scripting noob) you let the script look at the 2 columns in the needed page. and then run the script depending on the column with an if variable?

Comment: That's correct, @AntonyGeldof. If this helped, please upvote or accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

The onEdit trigger should not be run manually. The Spreadsheet service will pass the e object when the trigger is run via any edits in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, i always test the script "in action" to make sure it triggers (triggers set up) But I got the error messages any way.